# How can I give dynamic id name in HTML on condition in angular?

Tags: angular

I need to give id name in HTML on condition.For example if I want to do that with css class I will do
with [ngClass].

```
[ngClass]="{'total': type != 'service-type', 'font-normal':type == 'service-type' }"
```

How can I do this if I want to give an id instead of class.
If i try

```
[id]="{'total': type != 'service-type', 'font-normal':type == 'service-type' }"
```

I get id="Object Object" in HTML so it is not working

Comment: You are assigning an object to the ID attribute, what kind of string would you want the ID to be?

Comment: The id attribute can't be an object. The id is a simple string. Try: id="{{type == 'service-type' ? ... : ...}}"

Comment: I know.But with ngClass it is working.It maks destrucuring behind the scenes.But it is not doing with [id].With ngClass we can give more class names at once

Comment: Exactly... id does not accept an object. Only one simple string. What value do you want for id?

Comment: total or price-catalog depending on condition

Comment: In both the cases you could use ternary operator to avoid stating the conditions explicetely. `[ngClass]="type == 'service-type' ? 'font-normal' : 'total'"` and `[id]="type == 'service-type' ? 'font-normal' : 'total'"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a ternary operator within the template -

For example,

```
[id]="(type != 'service-type' ? 'total': 'font-normal')"
```

For three conditions, you can chain the ternary operators -

```
[id]="( nameC == 'A' ? 'idA' : (nameC == 'B' ? 'idB' : 'idC' ) )"
```

But if there are many more conditions, I would recommend constructing the id in the component.ts file and then using it in the html. For example -

```
export class MyComponent {
    ngOnInit() {
        if (condition1) myId = 'A';
        if (condition2) myId = 'B';
        ....
    }
}
```

And in the component.html, just use the id

```
<p id={{myId}}></p>
```

Comment: It is good solution,but i will need extra condition,so three of them what is the solution for that ?

Comment: Updated solution

Answer (score 0):

are you looking to do something like this?

`[id]="type != 'service-type' ? 'total' : 'font-normal'"`